# New-AzAks powershell cmdlet lacks ability to specify server-app-id and server-app-secret needed to integrate with AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks

Azure cli provides the required parameters to specify server app credentials. However the powershell Az module cmdlet seems to accept only Client App credentials to integrate with Azure AD.

Any information on the same will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is true, nobody here can help you with that. You can file an issue on [Azure Powershell github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues).